# How to bind request params in spring 3.0?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm building a controller which takes a request from a third party service. This service have request 5 params which I need to bind to a `Message` class.

Say, I in request, I'm getting

```
?a=x&b=y&c=z&d=w&e=k&f=t
```

The Message class is

```
public class Message{
 String a;
 String b;
 String c;
 String d;
 String e;
 String f;
 public Message(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f){
     this.a=a;this.b=b;this.c=c;this.d=d;this.e=e;this.f=f;
 }
 ....// along with getters and setters
}
```

One option is to use `@RequestParam` in the method controller, but then I would have to pass all the parameters and then instantiate the `Message` object manually. I don't want to do that because the parameter count is too large.

Can this be done using init binder/web data binder? and how?

Comment: I don't understand... what values are you hoping to find in the field of the `Message` class?  There's no actual content in the query string example (e.g. what is `param=a` supposed to actually produce in the `a` field?)

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the message example. I want to bind the incoming request parameters to Message object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to make this work, just declare a `Message` parameter to your controller method:

```
@RequestMapping
public String handleRequest(Message message) {
   ...
}
```

Spring will bind each parameter to a property on `Message`, where it can find one. If `Message` has getters and setters (and a default constructor), it will just work.  If you want to use a non-default constructor, or direct field injection, you'll have to do more config work.

Comment: Hi Skaffman, thanks for this, what if in the request ?a=x&b=y&c=z&d=w&e=k&f=t param b need to be mapped to a Custom class JobType instead of String, say suppose class Message is like this Message{String a; JobType b; String c;.... and so on }

Comment: @user354161: Then do the conversion in `Message.setB(String b)`... easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to pass the Message object as a parameter for the controller's handler method, and the binding happens automatically. Your request param string would need to be like this though: `?a=x&b=y&c=z&d=w&e=&f=` because if you have `?param=a&param=b&param=c` then your message object would need to be:

```
class Message {
    List<String> param; // ends up holding strings "a","b","c",...
}
```

Which is not what you want (as far as I can see).

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry I have corrected the request params. Yes this is what i intend to do. What if in the Message class there is a custom field like private JobType c;How would this mapping occur?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any special work, just list the object you need, then Spring will cleanly bind your request parameters to your class instance.

Comment: Can you please provide an example so that it would be more helpful for the future users.